# deepcopy breaks the reference relationship in user-defined class

Tags: python, deep-copy

I define a class, in which there is a reference relationship.

Then I create an instance, after copy.deepcopy this instance, the reference relationship is gone, for example:

```
import numpy as np
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
        self.a = self.c[1,:]

ff0 = foo()
ff1 = copy.deepcopy(ff0)

ff1.c +=np.array([10,10])
print(ff1.a)

ff0.c +=np.array([10,10])
print(ff0.a)
```

Output:

```
[3 4]
[13 14]
```

But I want to see such a output:

```
[13 14]
[13 14]
```

Can anyone help me to preserve this relationship?

Thank you in advance~

Comment: Then why are you using `copy.deepcopy`?  A class can provide a `__deepcopy__` method if you want customised behaviour.

Comment: It's actually a tree node, I want the leaf node get all property of root node, then apply changing to it

Comment: So you want `[13 14][23 24]` as output?

Comment: Then maybe you should create a new object?  I a tree all nodes are potentially root nodes.  You should pass the data (the np arrays) as arguments to the initialiser, rather than hard-code it.

Comment: sorry, I missed this part, I want them to be the same, namely both [13 14]

Comment: Because there are some functions in the object to use self.a, and I don't want to type self.c[1,:] because it's not convenient. So I need this relationship.

Comment: yes @cdarke, you are right, I can initialize another object.... it's not straight forward because the object also record some history data, but I can walk around it

Answer (score 0):

I got a walk around to this problem:

```
import numpy as np
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
        self.a = self.c[1,:]
    def copy(self):
        cp = copy.deepcopy(self)
        cp.a = cp.c[1,:]
        return cp

ff0 = foo()
ff1 = ff0.copy()

ff1.c +=np.array([10,10])
print(ff1.a)

ff0.c +=np.array([10,10])
print(ff0.a)
```

Output:

```
[13 14]
[13 14]
```